# basis for eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue that reduces to I?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

every single example I ever encountered for finding eignspace basis' always was a situation where the reduced matrix had a null space of 1 or more. but what if after plugging in the eignenvalue and reducing, there are no free variables, leading to a reduced matrix of I and no vectors in the basis? is it an empty basis? is this basis an empty set? I was hoping I could find a quick answer to this, I can't seem to find it anywhere online.

such as basis for the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue -1 for the matrix A =

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&4\\
      2&3
    \end{array}
\right] $$

since after I plug in eigenvalue -1 to the characteristic eq. it reduces to I giving me no free variables, and no t parameters, how do I find the basis? is it an empty set basis?

Comment: Whenever there is a non-trivial homogenous solution $AX=0$ or $(A-\lambda I)X=0$, there is always a free parameter because any constant multiple of $X$ is also a solution.

Comment: so if there is a free parameter what is it? because it seems like the solution is x1= 0 and x2=0, theres no parameter t, so how are you supposed to express the basis? is it {(0,0)}?

Comment: $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 4\\2 & 3\end{array}\right]-(-1)I = \left[\begin{array}{cc}2 & 4 \\ 2 & 4\end{array}\right]$ has null space $t\left[\begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$ where $t$ can be anything.

Comment: damnit, somehow i either reduced the matrix wrong or plugged in the  values wrong.. there goes over an hour fixating on 1 mysteri0us error >.<

Comment: I wish I could get all those hours back, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ then it cannot happen the row reduced matrix $A - \lambda I$ lacks at least one free variable.

the reason is if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ then $det(A - \lambda I) = 0.$ this means $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible and the $rank(A) \le n-1.$ this in turn implies that null space of $A - \lambda I$ is non trivial. this guarantees at least one free variable.

this is the reason we are able to find a nonzero vector(eigenvector)$u$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $A u = \lambda u, u \neq 0.$

p.s. you may not need this information but the dimension of $A - \lambda A$ is called the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ and tells you the number of jordan blocks associated with $\lambda.$